# Functions not showing in Azure Function app UI

Tags: windows, azure, azure-functions

I have simple repository https://github.com/meerfolk/SR-Functions created with https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools and when I try to deploy it on linux function app - all works fine. But when I try to deploy it on windows function app. Functions list is empty.

Does anybody know causes of that behavior?

Comment: Is there any deployment error message?

Comment: @TonyJu No in logs I see "Deployment successful." message without any previous error

Comment: You can go to kudu webstite to check if your function is there. `https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole `. Under `site/wwwroot` folder

Comment: Thank you @TonyJu I'm already use it and all my files is there, but not showing in UI

Comment: @TonyJu I try to use classic UI before and has the same result. I'll check it several days later and toggle your answer if it helps )))

Answer (score 0):

There will be some issues when using the new UI. You can try to switch to classic UI to check if the function will show there. Also, you can leave a feedback there.

[image]

If you still can not see the function list in the classic UI, you can try to redeploy it several days later.